# PHP App Engine Flex serving SPA and API

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible, google-app-engine-php

My goal is to serve a SPA and PHP api on the same site. I would like to be able to browse the website at mywebsite.com, and request api calls at mywebsite.com/api/.

My directory structure is:

```
public
|
+-- index.html 
+-- api
     |
     index.php
```

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public
```

Navigation to mywebsite.com gives a 404 because public/index.php doesn't exist.

So I tried this app.yaml:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public
  front_controller_file: index.html
```

And I can access mywebsite.com normally since index.html is the default file, but api/index.php is still 404.

Is something like this possible on App Engine php flex? I've read the docs- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `front_controller_file` in the `runtime_config`.
Create a file named `nginx-app.conf` with the following content:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
}

location /api {
  try_files $uri /api/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Then re-deploy. Both URL will work.

Comment: Thank you. One thing I noticed was mywebsite.com/api seems to have an infinite loop. However, mywesite.com/api/ works fine.

Comment: I removed the trailing slash from the example above.